# How to Insert rows if cell is smaller than 0

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody please help me write a VB Code to do the following:
If the Cell value in `AL2` is smaller that 0, then insert a row from Cells `N3:AL3` 
and If Cell Value in `AL2` is bigger than 0, then insert a row from Cells `A3:L3` 
Would greatly appreciate.

;)

Comment: Hi Theresa. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share with us what you've tried or the code you've written to accomplish this so we can assist you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve your desired results, you could do it under a Worksheet Change event, so every time the value of the cell AL2 changes the code is executed, as below, this code should be placed under the worksheet you are using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required

If Target.Address = "$AL$2" Then
    If Target.Value < 0 Then
    'check if value is below 0
        ws.Range("N3:AL3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        'insert into N3:AL3
    ElseIf Target.Value > 0 Then
    'check if value is above 0
        ws.Range("A3:L3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        'insert into A3:L3
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Another way is to create a sub routine this won't be executed automatically and you would expect the user to click and call that using a command button or something similar:

```
Sub Conditional_Insert()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required

If ws.Range("AL2").Value < 0 Then
'check if value is below 0
    ws.Range("N3:AL3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'insert into N3:AL3
ElseIf ws.Range("AL2").Value > 0 Then
'check if value is above 0
    ws.Range("A3:L3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    'insert into A3:L3
End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Further to the comments I believe the following will do what you expect, one thing to point out is that if the value is 0 in Column AL the code will do nothing for that row:

```
Sub Conditional_Insert()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1st")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AL").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column AL

For i = 1 To LastRow
'loop from row 1 to Last
    If ws.Cells(i, 38).Value < 0 Then
    'if value is less than 0 then
        ws.Range("N" & i + 1 & ":AL" & i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        'insert row in N:AL
        ws.Range("AL1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AL1:AL" & LastRow)
        'Autofill formula in Column AL
    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 38).Value > 0 Then
        ws.Range("A" & i + 1 & ":L" & i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        'insert row in A:L
        ws.Range("AL1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AL1:AL" & LastRow)
        'Autofill formula in Column AL
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @TheresaKuhn not sure what you mean by "whole worksheet of values in the AL rows" but could you please mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Xabier, Looks like its working, My only problem is I have a whole worksheet of values in the AL rows which needs rows inserted in the same way. The columns im working with in my sheet is from : A1: L3500 and N1:AL3500 each of these rows needs this code. Is there a way to do it all in one code?    What Im doing in this sheet is I am comparing (reconing) on report with another report, and if there is a diffrence as in Col AL1:AL3500 it must insert rows in either the first report (left) or the other report (right),   Can I upload my sheet somewhere so you can have a look at it?

Comment: Thank you, where do I mark your response as an answer?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q6ytw_NGuDVTwyU0L8_cSeo3na_zjqxZ

Comment: @TheresaKuhn I've now updated my answer, hope this helps... Please do mark my response as an answer. Thanks. :)